# How can I get access to context variables from class components within react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I need to have access to a variable called "value" from my React-Context called "ChatbotContext" using a class component (called "Frage").

However, when I use useContext, I receive the error message that Hooks are only allowed within react functions.

How can I access context variables inside my class component "Frage"?

Here is my (obviously) wrong attempt to access the value from the context

```
import ChatbotContext from "../../Context/Chatbot/chatbotContext";

const chatbotContext = useContext(ChatbotContext);
const { value } = chatbotContext;
console.log(value);

class Frage extends Rete.Component {
  constructor() {
    super("Frage");
  }

  // Build node elements
  builder(node) {
    // new input
    var inp = new Rete.Input("input1", "Input", numSocket, true);
    // new output1
    var out1 = new Rete.Output("output1", "Correct", numSocket, false);
    // new output2
    var out2 = new Rete.Output("output2", "Incorrect", numSocket, false);
    // new control1
    var ctrl1 = new MyControl(
      this.editor,
      node,
      "chatbottext",
      "Welches ist der höchste Berg der Welt?"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Frage is a class component, and you're trying to use useContext which can be only used in a functional component. In your case, you can use context like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UserContext from './UserContext'

class HomePage extends Component {
  static contextType = UserContext

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.context

    console.log(user) // { name: 'Sagar', loggedIn: true }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{user.name}</div>
  }
}
```

Hope this answer is helpful. Thanks